# What's the meaning of "at most" in logic?

Tags: logic, terminology

I am having difficulty in finding meaning of the words "at most" in mathematics or more precisely in logic. It probably is to some extent a language and/or philosophy problem.

For example when we say "we can do ... with at most $x$ ... ". Does that mean that we can't do it with more than $x$ or does it mean that we can do it with less than or equal to x, but maybe also more?

Comment: It would be better to provide a full example of he language that puzzles you.  In general, if we say something like "this algorithm takes at most $n$ steps to conclude." then we are saying that the number of necessary steps is $≤n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word "with" is a bit ambiguous here. Suppose you said

> We can nurdle any doohickey with at most $n$ widgets.

There could be (at least) two different, almost opposite, contexts.

1. Widgets are something a doohickey has, which make it harder to nurdle. We are saying that provided a doohickey doesn't have too many widgets, we will be able to nurdle it.
2. Widgets are used for nurdling things. We are saying we can always nurdle whatever doohickey we want, and we can guarantee not using too many widgets to do so.

In both cases we are not claiming the converse. It is possible in case 1 that we can also nurdle some doohickeys which have more than $n$ widgets, but it is also possible that we can't (or that we just don't know). In case 2, we can always avoid using more than $n$ widgets, if we want to, but perhaps we could choose to be wasteful and use more than $n$.

(You can make the statement unambiguous by replacing "with" with "having" for the first meaning, or "using" for the second.)

Comment: What about "We can color a graph with at most x colors."?

Comment: @timtam that's the second case. We can colour it in such a way as to avoid using more than $x$ colours. In that example we almost certainly could be inefficient and choose to use more colours.

Comment: So what is the difference between „We can color a graph with at most x colors.“ and „We can color a graph with x colors.“? In both cases we could be inefficient, so what meaning does „at most“ add?

Comment: @timtam Not much, but you might need "at most" in case it is possible the graph has fewer than $x$ vertices (you can't use more colours than there are vertices). For example, we can colour any graph which is a tree using at most $2$ colours, but you need the "at most" since there is a $1$-vertex tree.

Comment: ... and of course, sometimes we just add "at most" to save the trouble of working out whether we really need it :)

Comment: Isn‘t this meaning of „at most“ biased, since we know that we want the numbers of colors to be low? For example „We can color a house with at most x colors.“ Here we are not aiming for a low number, but a high number (assuming we like our house to be colourful), thus the meaning of „at most“ would set a bound for the number of colours that can be used.

Comment: In other words, doesn‘t the use of „at most“ set a bound for the numbers of colors we can use to color the graph as well?

Comment: @timtam If I meant $x$ is an upper bound on what's possible, rather than what's necessary, I would say "we can't colour [whatever] with more than $x$ colours" (I used a similar expression above).

Comment: So when I say I can fit at most 5 people in my car, I could potentially fit more? I am not saying you are wrong, I am wondering whether your definition is the correct one or a correct one of many. Isn‘t „at most“ ambiguous?

Answer (score 0):

"At most" means that many or less.

> I can fit at most 5 people in my car.
>
> The auditorium seats at most 100 people.
>
> The algorithm will converge in at most 1000 iterations.
>
> The express checkout can be used with at most 10 items.

In all of these cases, the action can or will performed with X items or fewer. If you have more than X, the action is not possible (seating 150 people in the auditorium), or alternatively, the action will not occur with more than X (the algorithm converging in 1200 iterations).